# How to make ActiveMQ nodes keep their database synchronized?

Tags: activemq, zookeeper

I have 3 servers with `Zookeeper` and `ActiveMQ` installed.
Everything seems to be working fine, however, when one of my `node` dies, and a new `election` occurs, however the new `leader` don't have the same `database` state as the other leader had.

Any idea why this is happening ? I can see that the `followers` are attaching to the `leader`, which I understand that they are able to communicate with each other. Is this correct ? What are the points that I might be missing here in order for this synchronization to happen ?

This is how I'm setting my `activemq.xml` related to `replicaDB`:

```
...
<persistenceAdapter>

    <replicatedLevelDB
        directory="${activemq.data}/leveldb"
        replicas="3"
        bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:61618"
        zkAddress="queue1.company.com:2881,queue2.company.com:2881,queue3.company.com:2881"
        zkPassword="unique_password_for_queue_1"
        zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores"
        hostname="queue3.company.com"
    />


</persistenceAdapter>
<sslContext>
    <sslContext keyStore="/opt/activemq/conf/queue3.jks" keyStorePassword="unique_password_for_keystore_at_queue_1" trustStore="/opt/activemq/conf/queue3.jts" trustStorePassword="unique_password_for_truststore_at_queue_1" />
</sslContext>
...
```